# A lot of classes are missing after upgrading reactor-netty from 0.7.x to 0.8.x. Do we have a document explaining the upgrade process?

Tags: reactor-netty

I am trying to upgrade spring boot and it looks like reactor-netty have removed reactor.ipc package with all it's classes.
I am trying to find a document/pointers which can help me understand what is the new equivalent for reactor.ipc package.

I looked at: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/releases for what's new section for 0.8.0 release(which actually removed these classes/package), but there is no link available.

I would appreciate if there is a doc or some note which can help in the transition for 0.7.x to 0.8.x release.

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to migrate

Comment: I was upgrading spring boot from 2.0.8 to 2.1.4 and had hit this issue with reactor-netty.

Comment: Reactor Netty is hidden behind Spring Boot/Spring Framework. Do you customise the server/client? That's the only thing that is exposed.